# How to fix hibernating/power problems on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, power-management, hibernate

I realized that whenever I turn on my notebook it is completely out of battery. I realized, then, that whenever I power off the computer, it turns off, but a light on the side of the computer remains on indicating that the computer is on. I'm suspecting that the system is just hibernating, and not shutting down properly. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks in advance for your attention!

Comment: There is "suspend", "hibernate" and shut down. "suspend" would leave your computer consuming battery, but that should be very few. Likely your computer does not suspend at all. For help, you will need to provide detail on the computer.

Comment: I have a recently bought Aspire 3, Acer. This problem has recently appeared. Also, I have a dual-boot WIndows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. When I shut down the computer in Windows, it powers off correctly. This problems olny occurs when I am using Ubuntu. @vanadium